# could not be able to work with upload file logic in php

Tags: php

I have a php code fragment as

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file_name = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name)) 
   {
     $success = true;
     $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
   }
   else 
   {
      $success = false;
      $message = "Error while uploading";
   }
}
else 
{
      $success = false;
      $message = "Required Field Missing";
}
$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

when I try to upload a file using `Postman` I get as error

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/Arshay.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/my_domain/public_html/android_api/dum_cv.php on line 9

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpFPW9sg' to 'uploads/Arshay.png' in /home/my_domain/public_html/android_api/dum_cv.php on line 9
{"success":false,"message":"Error while uploading"}
```

how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please check file permissions.

Comment: Where? on server?

Comment: Yes please, the server or local machine where you are uploading the files.

Comment: Its a remote host, How can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$target_file_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: OK this gives me message as upload successful, but I've to upload to  `$target_dir = "uploads/";` directory!!

Comment: $target_file_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); the folder "uploads"  must be exists

Comment: or          $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
 $target_file_name = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `$target_dir` does not exists.

Check the target directory before you move files.

```
if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
    if (!mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true)) {
        exit(json_encode(['success'=>false, 'message'=>'failed to create target directory']));
    }
}
```